# How to display angular form validation error inside angular bootstrap popover?

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-bootstrap

I am new to angular js. I want to show the form error in angular bootstrap popover at the right hand side of the element.I tried to create the directive and I got an element when it changes classes. But I don't have an idea how to move next.

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
var app=angular.module('formExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function(form) {
      if (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
      }
      $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
  }]);
app.directive("alert", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        priority: -1000,
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl){
          scope.$watch(function() {console.log(ele.attr('class')); })
          if (ctrl) {
            console.log("applying custom behaviour to input: ", ele.attr('id'));
            // ... awesomeness here
          }
        }
    };
});
})(window.angular);
```

I just want to show the error message

1. <strike>when user clicks save button(all form fields error message)</strike>
2. <strike>blur of an element(only for the element which is lost the focus)</strike>

Here is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xaIQqiIFsd6yZDWFZeWh?p=preview) which I tried to get the message.

**Update**

Somehow I displayed the angular bootstrap popover and close button which closes the popover.

I have two issues in the current [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/F34YgDyY1cDMp5ZLAN6P?p=preview).

1. I want to display the error message inside my popover template
   respective to the element where it is getting opened. I need this
   template because I need a close button.
2. Once I closed the popover if the field is empty and user clicks
   submit the popover is not opening next time. I want to display error
   message each and every time of submit.

Comment: In my experience, `uib-popover`s were not designed to handle such dynamic content (like error validation).  I tried a similar approach in a project, and it ended up not being worth the trouble of using the `uib-popover`.  Instead, we just used css and `ng-class` to mimic the feel of the popovers.  Then our directives only had to handle when to hide/show the "popovers" based on our form.

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

How about putting your template like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
  <div class="gmePopover">
    <div class="popover-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" popover-toggle><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-content">
        somecontent
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Working Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/B8KXo0m6x7j0bgDjoKG9?p=preview).

**UPDATE:**

You can use angularjs foreach to loop through all errors in your form, then from there you can show the popover base on your element. Something like this: [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B8KXo0m6x7j0bgDjoKG9?p=preview)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app=angular.module('testApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize'], function($httpProvider) {});
  app.controller("PopoverDemoCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.validate = function() {
        var _popover;
        var error = $scope.testForm.$error;
        angular.forEach(error.required, function(field){
            var message = 'This field (' + field.$name + ') is required';
            _popover = $('#' + field.$name).popover({
              trigger: 'manual',
              title: '<span class="text-info"><strong>title</strong></span>'+
            '<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;#' + field.$name + '&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
              content: message,
              html: true
            });

            return $('#' + field.$name).popover("show")
        });
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I need the content for popover respective to the parent element . I dont know what is the difference between my updated plunker with yours.

Comment: The difference: I placed the myPopoverTemplate.html inside a ng-template. I'm not sure what do you mean by respective to the parent element. A simplified example would help, for us to help.

Comment: Ok, for example, in the given plunker , consider first textbox is username and second text box password. if user clicks submit button, without enter any values (i.e both text box is empty) , then we have to show 'Please enter username ' in first popover, and in second popover we have to show 'Please enter password'.

Comment: ...Is there a way if we can find out the element already opened the popover. When I print the error object if the element didnt match the certain pattern then for same element I am getting two objects with in the error. In that case, I have to stop the element opening another popover.i.e.Required is not only the validation.

Comment: not tested but I believe you want $yourElement.data()['bs.popover'].tip().hasClass('in') it will return true if the popover is visible

Answer (score 2):

You can create a directive that intercepts the `$setSubmitted` method of the `FormController`.

You can find more information regarding the method [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setSubmitted)

Please find working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/v9zLz8ys/1/)

When this directive intercepts the `$setSubmitted` method, we can notify another directive to show the validation errors in a [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

I am working under the following assumptions(feel free to correct me):

- you will be using a form tag
- on your form tag you will have `ng-submit="nameOfForm.$valid && vm.onSubmit()"`

The solution works with two directives:

`submitNotify` and `popoverValidation`

`submitNotify` notifies `popoverValidation` when the form is submitted, the `popoverValidation` directive then shows the form errors if there are any.

## Directive 1 : `submitNotify`

```
directive('submitNotify', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'form',
        controller: function SubmitNotify() { },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, form) {                
            var $setSubmitted = form.$setSubmitted;
            form.$setSubmitted = function () {
                $setSubmitted.bind(form)();
                scope.$broadcast('onSubmitNotify');
            };
        }
    };
})
```

## Explanation:

- Can only be used as a attribute directive
- Requires a `form` tag, or `ngForm`

## The link function:

The link function replaces the `$setSubmitted` function with a callback function. The callback function notifies the `popoverValidation` directive that the form has been submitted.

## Directive 2: `popoverValidation`

```
directive('popoverValidation', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['ngModel', '^submitNotify'],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, require) {
            scope.$on('onSubmitNotify', function () {
                var ngModel = require[0];
                if (!ngModel.$valid) {
                    showPopover(ngModel.$error);
                }
            });

            function showPopover( $error) {
                var options = {
                    content: getValidationErrorsHtml($error),
                    html: true,
                    template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content popover-content-errors"></div></div>',
                    title: '<span class="text-info"><strong>Error</strong></span><button type="button" data-dismiss="popover" class="close">&times;</button>',
                    trigger: 'manual'
                }
                $(element).popover(options);
                $(element).on('shown.bs.popover', hidePopover);
                $(element).popover('show');                    
            }

            function hidePopover() {
                $(this).next('.popover').find('button[data-dismiss="popover"]').click(function (e) {
                    $(element).popover('hide');
                });
            }

            function getValidationErrorsHtml($error) {
                var errors = [];

                if ($error.required) {
                    errors.push(requiredErrorMessage());
                }

                if ($error.email) {
                    errors.push(invalidEmailAddress());
                }

                var errorHtml = '<ul class="list-group">';

                for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                    errorHtml += '<li class="list-group-item">' + errors[i] + '</li>';
                }

                errorHtml += '</ul>';

                return errorHtml;
            }

            function requiredErrorMessage() {
                return 'This field is required';
            }

            function invalidEmailAddress() {
                return 'Please enter a valid email address';
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

## Explanation:

- Can only be used as a attribute directive
- Requires a `submitNotify` tag on the parent `form`

## The link function:

- The `popoverValidation` directive gets notified that the form is submitted
- It checks if the `ng-model` binded property is valid
- If not valid a popover gets displayed

Complete HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyFormController as vm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && vm.onSubmit()" submit-notify="" novalidate>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Form Validation with Popovers</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" required ng-model="person.firstName" popover-validation="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" required ng-model="person.surname" popover-validation="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="person.email" popover-validation="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## Some CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .popover-content-errors {
        padding:0px;
    }

    .popover-content-errors .list-group {
        margin-bottom:0px
    }

    .popover-content-errors .list-group-item {
        border-left:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    .popover-content-errors .list-group-item:first-child {
        border-top:none;
    }

    .popover-content-errors .list-group-item:last-child {
        border-bottom:none;
    }
</style>
```

## MyFormController

```
controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    var self = this;
    $scope.person = {
        email:'john.doe.com'
    }
    self.onSubmit = function () {   
        console.log('MyFormController.onSubmit');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: ...I didn't went through completely. But I just got into the plunker and I entered the correct email address.Still the error is not disappeared.